# Message: no such element: Unable to locate element Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait

I am trying to click on a button but getting this error message:
The element I am trying to click does exist on the page but I am not sure why it's saying that the element does not exist:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class="vote_button mfp-voteText"]"}
```

Below is my code:

```
driver.get('https://trupanion.com/canada/members/contest?pixlee_album_photo_id=427049511')

time.sleep(10)

try:
    vote = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="vote_button mfp-voteText"]')
    vote.click()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Below is the XPath in chrome dev tool which shows it's correct:

[image]

Comment: Maybe because the web page is not loaded? I see the error: Error 1020
This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks.

Comment: The element is loaded. I did check it after the error but it was there. If there any fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired element is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://trupanion.com/members/contest?pixlee_album_photo_id=427049511')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#pixlee_lightbox_iframe")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.vote_button.mfp-voteText"))).send_keys("test")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://trupanion.com/members/contest?pixlee_album_photo_id=427049511")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='pixlee_lightbox_iframe']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='vote_button mfp-voteText']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: VOTED]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Comment: haha.. @DebanjanB. it was you. I can not really recognize you.

Comment: How??? At some point, I've gotten your help and referenced a lot of your questions and answers in the scraping & selenium field. So I know only your face, not remembered your name.

Comment: @jis0324 Sounds great, keep visiting [Selenium Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) we are regular there :)

Comment: You disguised as a dog, but I can see a real face for a little time. Please note that I am holding a long sword. LOL.................

Answer (score 1):

It inside a `<frame>` tag, switch it first:

```
driver.get('https://trupanion.com/canada/members/contest?pixlee_album_photo_id=427049511')

time.sleep(10)

try:
    #switch it first
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id('pixlee_lightbox_iframe'))
    vote = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="vote_button mfp-voteText"]')
    vote.click()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

But note `time.sleep(..)` is a bad idea.

You can learn selenium waits here:

[selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

And for switch a frame:

[.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it)

Although your xpath will work, the css selector looks better:

```
vote = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.vote_button.mfp-voteText')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `css selector` instead of `XPATH` with the `WebdriverWait()` function. It will wait X seconds for an element to be clickable and will click it as soon as it is present. However, you need to switch to the frame that you have to find by a `frame` selector.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

self.webdriver.switch_to_frame(self.webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector('frame'))
try:
    WebDriverWait(webdriver,time).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,path)))
except Exception as e:
   print(e)
```